# jquery ui drag and drop - divs not stacking

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I created a example for draging a div into another and appending it to the div it is droped in.

http://jsfiddle.net/22et84qc/

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({stack:"draggable"});
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
drop: function(ev, ui) {
    var offset = ui.helper.offset();
        ui.helper.appendTo( this ).offset( offset );
    }
});
```

It is working fine but when I have to divs I first can stack them but when I drag on of them again they won't stack.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the "." in stack:"draggable"

Fixed code:

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({stack:".draggable"});
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
drop: function(ev, ui) {
    var offset = ui.helper.offset();
        ui.helper.appendTo( this ).offset( offset );
    }
});
```

Comment: I updated the code, but it is still not stacking right. http://jsfiddle.net/22et84qc/1/